# How can I bend a cylinder?

Tags: modeling, rendering

I want to bend a cylinder like a straw. How do I do that?
The picture shows what I want to recreate.[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with the *Mirror* modifier:

- Create a cylinder, give it a *Mirror* modifier, create an empty, move it a bit away from the cylinder, select it as the *Mirror Object* of your cylinder, select the right axis, enable *Bisect* on the same axis:

[image]

Rotate the empty until your cylinder cross as you wish, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to rotate 5° by 5°:

[image]